# The multi-part identifier "Export_Shipping.site_num" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error "The multi-part identifier "Export_Shipping.s_num" could not be bound.". My target table is web_shipping and the source is export_web_shipping.
How to fix this specific Update query ?

```
UPDATE Shipping
SET Shipping.s_num= Export_Shipping.s_num
FROM Shipping a, Export_Shipping b 
WHERE b.[order_id]= a.order_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave `Export_Shipping` an alias `b`. So use `b` and not `Export_Shipping`.
Also, I would use a `join`.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.s_num = b.s_num
FROM Shipping a JOIN Export_Shipping b 
ON b.[order_id]= a.order_id
```

Comment: huge thanks for the quick response. I totally forgot that.